# Is deep ng-content select possible at all?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngcontent, ng-content

Suppose I want to transclude such a markup into ng-content:

```
<div aaa>
  AAA
</div>
<div aaa bbb>
  BBB
</div>
```

For this I can use selectors (which look like regular CSS ones):

```
<ng-content select="div[aaa]"></ng-content>
----- some other content here -----
<ng-content select="div[aaa][bbb]"></ng-content>
```

But what if I have this content (I can't get rid of 'section' tag):

```
<section>
  <div aaa>
    AAA
  </div>
  <div aaa bbb>
    BBB
  </div>
</section>
```

What selectors can I use to get the same result? This doesn't work for me:

```
<ng-content select="section div[aaa]"></ng-content>
----- some other content here -----
<ng-content select="section div[aaa][bbb]"></ng-content>
```

Neither this:

```
<ng-content select="section>div[aaa]"></ng-content>
----- some other content here -----
<ng-content select="section>div[aaa][bbb]"></ng-content>
```

Is there any workaround for this? Why the selector doesn't work as CSS one? Is this by design? I can't find the reason on docs...

Will it help if 'section' tag is replaced with 'ng-template' or 'ng-container'?

Comment: just a quick question i have is why would you use two ng-content if you are displaying something under section for example why don't you do  <ng-content select="section"></ng-content> and then pass both the divs

Comment: Because both ng-content are in different places on the page, separated from each other with some other content.

Comment: You cannot use ::ng-deep in an ng-content select string either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible with ng-content.

There are alternatives for what you want to do, however they are a bit more complex.

My preferred way to do this is to use Angular CDK portals.
For further information see:

- https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-cdk-portals-b02f66dd020c
- https://medium.com/@sumn2u/dynamic-ui-using-portals-in-angular-cdk-6051988b0f81